# Extract URL from Angular JS link using Selenium WebDriver w Python

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

What I want to do is parse the URL from a "Visit Website" link on

https://www.truelocal.com.au/business/index-partners/canberra

Source reads as follows:

```
<span class="text-frame" ng-class="(vm.getHaveSecondaryWebsites()==true) ? 'with-aditional-item':''">
    <span ng-click="vm.openLink(vm.getReadableUrl(vm.getPrimaryWebsite()),'_blank')" role="button" tabindex="0">Visit website</span>
</span>
```

(I think that is Angular??)

When the link is clicked the new tab opens the URL

I can't see the URL in the source to parse it (using Python and Selenium)

Is there a way to retrieve the URL using Python & Selenium? ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.truelocal.com.au/business/index-partners/canberra')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Visit website"]').click()

# Switching to the 2nd newly opened tab
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
print(driver.current_url)

# Switching to the 1st tab
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
print(driver.current_url)
```

Output:

```
http://www.indexpartners.com.au/
https://www.truelocal.com.au/business/index-partners/canberra
```

Comment: Perfect! Well done. Thank you so much for your help @Ali